# Facebook messanger API:change button styles and colors

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Currently the facebook messanger API supports different types of buttons

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons

But is there any way to change the default style of that button

eg:Adding custom color,change border

Is it possible with API??